# Batch updates with Sequel gem

Tags: ruby, sequel, batch-updates

I need to do multiple updates on a PostgreSQL database at once. To make it faster, I would like to avoid continually changing context between my ruby application and the database.

I've learned about the [#update_sql](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/evanfarrar/opensprints/Sequel%2FDataset%3Aupdate_sql) method, however my strategy to queue those queries is not working. I'm making a list `sqls` which holds many update strings, and then `db[sqls.join(';') + ';']`. If instead of executing this line I decide to print the resulting sql and copy/paste to the database it works.

Why doesn't this work? How can I send multiple updates in a single sql?

Answer (score 1):

Sequel doesn't offer an API that supports multiple queries in a single statement.  If the driver you are using supports, it, you can use Sequel::Database#synchronize to get access to the driver connection object, and call methods directly on that.